How to test whether the values in one matrix are significantly smaller than in another matrix?
I have a set of proteins for which I have predicted structures using two distinct methods. For each protein, both methods have generated 5 different structures. My goal is to compare the stability of the structures produced by Method 1 against those produced by Method 2 for each protein.
To do this, I have computed the root mean square distance (which measures dissimilarity, and is >= 0) within each set of 5 models. As a result, for each protein, I now have two symmetric 5x5 matrices.
My question is: How can I determine if one method consistently produces more stable results than the other? What statistical test would be appropriate to compare these matrices?

How do you wish to quantify or otherwise characterize "stability" of results?
